# Как парсить ссылку которая поялвяется на сайте | JS

Tags: javascript

Пишу бота телеграмм на JS.
Бот парсит сайт и выводит данные.
Проблема вот в чем, на сайте каждый день появляется новая ссылка с данными которые нужно парсить.
Как ее находить и все автоматизировать чтобы скрипт сам находил эту ссылку и выводил данные?

Comment: Вам стоит добавить хотя бы пример HTML ссылки с её минимальным окружением и адресом, чтобы кто-то смог попробовать вам помочь.

Comment: Пожалйста прочитайте [ask] и [mre]